# use xlsread function in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

let us consider following data

```
X   Y
2   3
4   5
8   7
11  7.5
14  8
18  9
21  12
```

i have used following commands

```
>> Y=xlsread('regression','Sheet1','f5:f11');
>> X=xlsread('regression','Sheet1','e5:e11');
```

because  name of excel file is regression,it is at Sheet1 and columns are corresponding

```
f5:f11
e5:e11
```

but it returns me  empty vectors,what is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that you're reading correctly, then probably you have two files names `regression.xls` and `regression.xlsx` on the PATH respectivley, former being empty at `e5:f11`

`xlsread` suffixes default extension, if not provided.

From [*here*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#inputarg_filename)

> If you do not include an extension, xlsread searches for a file with
>   the specified name and a supported Excel extension. xlsread can read
>   data saved in files that are currently open in Excel for Windows.

<sup>*PS: I cannot recreate this behavior on my PC, with same file name and data*</sup>

Comment: i have corrected,there was some unknown error :D

Comment: usually  on the top it was written x and y ,name of variables,i have typed it again and it was working